# No wifi option on Ubuntu (18.04 and 16.04)

Tags: networking, 18.04, intel-wireless

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but I wouldn't get connected to the wifi as there was no wifi option. I checked /lib/firmware and my Intel AC 9260 wifi driver ucode was there, I tried downloading another one from Intel too but that didn't make a difference.

```
nvan@R2700x:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`
    06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2526] (rev 29)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

nvan@R2700x:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.583006] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.596295] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.615392] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9260, REV=0x324
[    4.622171] kernel BUG at /build/linux-5s7Xkn/linux-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.c:425!
[    4.622216] Modules linked in: snd_hda_intel amd64_edac_mod(-) snd_hda_codec iwlmvm(+) snd_hda_core edac_mce_amd kvm_amd(-) snd_hwdep mac80211 kvm snd_pcm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi iwlwifi aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd wmi_bmof snd_seq cfg80211 input_leds btusb snd_seq_device btrtl snd_timer btbcm btintel snd bluetooth soundcore ccp k10temp ecdh_generic mac_hid shpchp sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau mxm_wmi video ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops igb drm dca i2c_piix4 i2c_algo_bit ptp nvme ahci pps_core libahci nvme_core gpio_amdpt wmi gpio_generic
[    4.622335] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_rxq_alloc_rbs+0x1d0/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
[    4.622403]  _iwl_pcie_rx_init+0x252/0x710 [iwlwifi]
[    4.622414]  iwl_pcie_rx_init+0x2d/0x3c0 [iwlwifi]
[    4.622436]  ? iwl_mvm_nic_config+0xeb/0x120 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622448]  iwl_trans_pcie_start_fw+0x2a1/0x6c0 [iwlwifi]
[    4.622462]  iwl_mvm_load_ucode_wait_alive+0xec/0x2b0 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622490]  iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x8e/0x330 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622500]  ? iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x8e/0x330 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622510]  ? iwl_wait_init_complete+0x20/0x20 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622523]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x649/0x920 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622536]  ? iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x649/0x920 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622546]  _iwl_op_mode_start.isra.10+0x4c/0xa0 [iwlwifi]
[    4.622556]  iwl_opmode_register+0x75/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[    4.622573]  iwl_mvm_init+0x38/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
[    4.622739] RIP: iwl_pcie_rxq_alloc_rbs+0x1d0/0x1f0 [iwlwifi] RSP: ffffadbfc23fb8a8
```

Thank you for your help!
Sincerely,
Nick V

---

Update 1: 
I have tried to install the BackPort from this site [backport-iwlwifi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/commit/)
. However, I'm unable to install it due to lack of gcc. I also tried to install build-essential package, but without an internet connection, I'm clueless about how to proceed.

Comment: The fix looks to be complicated, see upstream bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199551

Comment: The fix is to download and install *build-essential* and all its dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies: https://packages.ubuntu.com/ Or walk the computer over to an ethernet cable and I can propose a 3 minute fix.

Comment: Hi @chili555, I now have ethernet access to the internet. Would you guide me through the 3 minutes fix? Thanks!

Comment: Please start with: `sudo apt update` then: `sudo apt install build-essential git` and I will finish up in a full answer in about an hour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please start with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git
```

Now do:

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
sudo make
sudo make install
```

The ‘make’ step takes a few moments; please be patient.

Now, we’ll write a conf file:

```
sudo -i
echo “options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is now working.

**EDIT**: You have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a newer kernel version, after the requested reboot, recompile:

```
cd backport-iwlwifi
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.

Please retain the files and these instructions for that time.

Comment: The wifi is up and running perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: You are the king! It is working!!!!!!! Linux Mint 19!!!

Comment: After this I am getting the message 'No Wi-Fi Adapter Found'

Comment: @Abbas Please start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 I have asked the question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075887/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-ubuntu-18-04-on-desktop. Can you please answer?

Comment: @chili555 this answer helped me fix my problem. I asked a question for this some time back https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220775/wifi-stopped-working-after-ubuntu-update and i almost gave up on using ubuntu since then.I am Glad i found your answer today !

Answer (score 3):

I found I had this issue when doing a dual boot of windows 10 and Ubuntu.  If I did a hibernate/sleep in windows somehow it would lock up the wifi chip/wifi driver and ubuntu couldn't access it.  The solution was to **1) disable fast boot on windows** and **2) make sure I "shut down" windows 10 instead of hibernating**.  Then windows 10 releases the wifi and all versions of ubuntu recognize wifi no problem.  Really an infuriating issue, I had hoped to be able to hibernate in windows, switch to Ubuntu, hibernate in ubuntu, switch back, but windows 10 just doesn't play nice :/

edit: here's a link to disabling windows 10 fast startup  https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

edit2: I was also seeing "failed with error -110"... I guess -110 is the windows-is-being-a-jerk error.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the easy options.  I presume you haven't turned the card off in the network settings, but what about the hardware kill switch?

```
andrew@big-red-wired:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE    SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   blocked unblocked
andrew@big-red-wired:~$
```

In my case, I have one wireless card, and I have it off in software, ON in the hardware.  All I did was use Network Manager to disable the wireless.  I got bit by this a few years back reinstalling for a friend who had a borked windows install and this was the problem.

HTH
Andrew.

edit:
If this is indeed the case,

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: I have checked the kill switch, but only Bluetooth appeared (all unblocked). I didn't see a type WLAN or wireless device.