# Wi-Fi doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (RTL8723BE)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, rtl8723be

When I installed Ubuntu for the first time I had to do some work with the terminal because my Wi-Fi reception was lower than on Windows:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ips=0 fwlps=0 ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

After updating Ubuntu to bionic beaver my Wi-Fi randomly stops and my browser says that I am not connected to internet. I need to turn off and on my Wi-Fi to use the network.
I searched on internet and I followed instructions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038807/863944) answer. Now my pc says `"no Wi-Fi adapter found"`

I tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

with a reboot. And I have also tried:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

but nothing.

`lshw -C` network says that my wireless net adapter is unclaimed:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:91200000-91203fff
```

What can I do? I am fairly new with Ubuntu.

Edit:

I have tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/635629/863944), but it says `"Unable to locate package rtlwifi-new-dkms"`

Comment: You can gain some information by running `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --follow`

Comment: did you try `sudo modprobe rtlwifi_new` sir?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri modprobe: FATAL: Module rtlwifi_new not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic

Comment: What is the result for `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be`

Comment: that drivers compatible for 16.04 at your link and uncompatible for 18.04 try this [driver](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+packages).

Comment: @Jeremy31 it shows nothing

Comment: Try `cd backport-iwlwifi && sudo make uninstall` then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 nothing, still no wifi adapter found

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and post your wireless script result

Comment: @Jeremy31 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/34GfqQm7KB/

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/WirelessEnabled=false/WirelessEnabled=true/' /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`   then `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source` then reboot

Comment: New wireless script results please `./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`  post URL from terminal

Comment: http://termbin.com/ldgk @Jeremy31

Comment: It seems the iwlwifi backports are still being used and are likely causing a conflict, you may need to use an older kernel until another new one is released.  You might also have wifi disabled in network manager

Comment: Here's a workaround using newer kernel: https://askubuntu.com/a/1085273/480481

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kernel version are you running?

You can type `uname -r` in a terminal to get it

I spent long hours to figure out that the problem had something to do with the 4.15.0-33-generic kernel. I switched to the previous one (-32) and everything worked again.

However, i just managed to install the "rtlwifi_new" you mentioned, and now wifi seems to be fine even on latest one.

So, on the 33 kernel, I plugged in the eth cable and executed the following commands:

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential git`
- `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/`
- `cd rtlwifi_new`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

And in `rc.local` script I've put these two commands:

- `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be`
- `sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1`

Then I rebooted the system

Hope this can help

Comment: my kernel is 4.15.0-33-generic, I executed the commands but nothing. I tried the previous kernel version (-32) and it still says no wifi adapter found, **but** I  can switch on and off the wifi, and and I can connect to wifi, oddly it shows me a ethernet icon instead of a wifi icon

Comment: Instructions in the answer worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with `4.15.0-33-generic`. Used `master` branch and options `ips=0 fwlps=0 ant_sel=1`

Answer (score 1):

That unload/reload of rtl8723be may not work. Under some circumstances, the chip remembers the ant_sel option and ignores the one set on antenna reload. The safer way is to create an options file in /etc/modprobe.d/ that sets the ant_sel option.

Also be aware that there have been changes in the btcoex code that changed the best value from 1 to 2.