# Wifi signal strength is suddenly low even if antenna is selected

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have realtek rtl8723be network adapter. I have installed the diver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/master/rtl8723be. I use following commands every time I turn on the computer:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

This worked well. But today I have problem with my wifi. It keeps disconnecting and the signal strength is really low even if the router is next to the computer. I don't see the other networks at all. I tried with `ant_sel=1` too but no luck. My Ubuntu version is 16.04. Is there any way to troubleshoot and fix the issue?

Comment: Is there any improvement with ant_sel=1?

Comment: @chili555 Tried it. But no improvement.

Comment: @abu_bua No. That question and answer is about the current setting I already have. My question is beyond that.

Comment: It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 has a bug. See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be

Comment: Alternatively. try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts