# Wifi Signal becomes very weak

Tags: wireless, 18.04, rtl8723be

I am using Realtek RTL8723BE wireless adapter on my Ubuntu 18.04.1.
I was using it since Ubuntu 16.04, there was the problem of weak signal and unable to detect any AP, so I found these command lines to fix the problem.

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|level'
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ips=0 ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Of course, the `ant_sel=1` can be change to 2 for another antenna.

It works well for 2 years, until the recent Linux Kernal 4.15.0-33, in this version of kernal, the signal becames weak again, and the command lines do not work anymore.
I will have to boots the 4.15.0-32 version everytime I start my laptop.

Anyone facing the same issue? Anyone have the soluntion to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi networks not found ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 has a bug.

Comment: Alternatively, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts