# Issue with Wi-Fi connection range with Ubuntu 18.04 and HP Laptop

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I have upgraded my HP pavilion laptop from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04. Initially it has issue with Wi-Fi connection. I had installed Wi-Fi realtek driver and it was working.

All of sudden it has stopped detecting my router Wi-Fi. When I move close to Wi-Fi router its working fine, but just within range of 1-2 meters. If I go far around 5 meters my Wi-Fi is not showing in available Wi-Fi list.

same Wi-Fi is working with my iPhone perfectly. I did try to connect my phone hotspot and its also working fine when phone is close to my laptop.

Is there any solution to fix this issue? or I just need to revert back to windows?

here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]

    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

    Kernel modules: rtl8723be

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)


0: hci0: Bluetooth

    Soft blocked: yes

    Hard blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no

    Hard blocked: no
```

Please let me know if need to update or downgrade my kernel.

Comment: What is result from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`  If it is rtl8723be, try using a kernel older than -33 as 33 has a bug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi networks not found ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 has a bug, boot using an older kernel. Alternatively, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts

Comment: @pomsky yes you are right there was issue with kernel V4.15.0-33, I have tried with -32 and its working fine. Thank you so much buddy fir your quick help and suggestion. Is there any way to set -32 as default boot kernel?

Comment: @TejashJethwa See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed with  kernel 4.17.0-041700:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~jsalisbury/lp1788997

as long as you select antenna 1:

```
modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```