# Wifi Signal Weak Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

Yesterday, I updated my HP Laptop from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04.
Since then, the WiFi signal is very weak. I have tried all the options with downloading new driver from git. And tried with both `ant_sel=1` and `ant_sel=2` but both gives weak signal. In 17.10 `ant_sel=2` used to work.

Any idea on what would have went wrong during the update?

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Sniper"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 94:65:2D:02:E3:91
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:159   Missed beacon:0
```

```
siddharth@siddharth-HP-Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm
                    ESSID:"Sniper"
```

This is when I sit next to the modem.

I have done the below steps:

1. Cloned latest rtlwifi_new from git
2. `make`
3. `sudo make install`
4. `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be`
5. `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2`
6. `sudo ip link set wlo1 up`
7. `sudo iw dev wlp13s0 scan`

At no point I got any error. Tried with `ant_sel=1` also.

Update:

Output of `lshw -C network`:

```
siddharth@siddharth-HP-Notebook:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: 30:e1:71:97:de:e0
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 58:00:e3:a7:14:cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.59 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user
```

Comment: This solution might help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229221/rtlwifi-rtl8723befw-bin-wireless-stop-working-then-laptop-needs-to-reboot-to

Comment: Also, you can find latest firmwares at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/commit/

Comment: What is the output of `lshw -C network`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi networks not found ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 has a bug. Alternatively, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts

Comment: both option didnt worked for me.... i changed the kernel to 4.13.0-46-generic

Comment: the iwlist wl01 scan returns
**wl01    Interface doesn't support scanning**

Could this be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wi-Fi doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (RTL8723BE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wi-fi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-rtl8723be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it ultimately. Thanks to the last post by @pomsky.

My kernel version was 33-generic so i **downgraded my kernel to 4.13.0-46-generic** as it was the last available. And now wifi is working fine in Ubuntu 18.4.1 LTS.

I performed rest of the steps too, i.e upgrading to the latest rtlwifi_new and setting ant_sel=2. But at the end needed a kernel downgrade.

Thank you for your help