# Weak WiFi signal in Xubuntu 18.04 on HP Stream 13, rtl8723be (NOT antenna selection, it does nothing)

Tags: drivers, wireless, xubuntu, realtek, rtl8723be

> **edit:** Two solutions have been mentioned but don't work for me:
>
> 1. Change antenna selection on wifi driver. This does not work for my problem. It seems it used to work for 16.04 LTS but that fix
>      apparently got broken in 18.04. This is a new install of Xubuntu and
>      I'd like to stick with 18.04 if I can.
> 2. Roll back kernel to 4.15.0-32-generic. This may be the right direction as it seems that there is a known bug for RTL8723BE driver
>      in 4.15.0-33 and onward, but the solutions linked are for Ubuntu
>      proper and have the user boot into advanced options. I'm running
>      Xubuntu and my boot menu has no advanced options. Again, this is a
>      fresh install of Xubuntu so I don't have any prior kernel versions
>      more than a couple weeks back, and I haven't been able to figure out
>      how to try to roll back the kernel in a Xubuntu distro.

I just installed Xubuntu 18.04 on my HP Stream 13-110ca as Windows 10 needs more storage than the 32GB SSD has.

I'm having a lot of difficulty with the WiFi. It's got a rtl8723be wireless card, and a lot of other posts suggest switching the antenna number, but none of them seem to make any difference. No matter what I select the strength is about -65 dbm on every option.

WiFi was working just fine in Windows 10 before the switch, so I know the antenna is connected.

Prod ID: P4B15UA#ABL

Please advise.

Thanks in advance,

Sarah

Hiere's the output from inxi -Fxz:

```
sarah@sarah-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: sarah-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13 Kernel: 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.31) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: HP product: HP Stream Notebook PC 13 v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: N/A
           Mobo: HP model: 817D v: 39.13 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Insyde v: F.1B date: 01/05/2016
Battery    BAT0: charge: 35.4 Wh 100.0% condition: 35.4/35.4 Wh (100%)
           model: Hewlett-Packard Primary status: Full
CPU:       Dual core Intel Celeron N3050 (-MCP-) 
           arch: Airmont rev.3 cache: 1024 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 6400
           clock speeds: max: 2160 MHz 1: 481 MHz 2: 638 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.06hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 400 (Braswell)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-33-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: rtl8723be port: 1000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: NA (-)
           ID-1: /dev/mmcblk0 model: N/A size: 31.3GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 29G used: 5.9G (22%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/mmcblk0p2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 44.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 160 Uptime: 11 min Memory: 766.1/1853.0MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191) inxi: 2.3.56 
sarah@sarah-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~$
```

Here's the output from lspci; lsusb

```
sarah@sarah-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~$ lspci; lsusb
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #4 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bb4:0ffe HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Desire HD (modem mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:0379 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
sarah@sarah-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~$
```

Here's the output from iwconfig

```
sarah@sarah-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~$ iwconfig
enp0s20u4u2  no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Chester"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: AC:20:2E:D4:58:08   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3922   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

sarah@sarah-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi networks not found ubuntu 18.04 with rtl8723be.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 has a bug. Alternatively, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wifi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)

Comment: It is a bug, leave the ant_sel=2 and see comment 21 at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997

Comment: I've tried the antenna select solution and it doesn't do anything. I'm willing to try to revert to an older kernel but I'm very new to Linux and don't know how to do that. It seems the most likely kernel would be back to v4.15.0-32. How do I revert to that? I'm running Xubuntu with kernel v4.15.0-34 now.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed with this kernel:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~jsalisbury/lp1788997

as long as you select antenna 1:

```
modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```