# Realtek rtl8623be back to low signal WiFi after update

Tags: 18.04, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I've had this issue before but after all the options I've found online I'm still no further forward this time.

I've got a HP Laptop with the rtl8723be wifi adapter. I've had issues in the passed with this driver and recently got it working with lwfinger's rtlwifi_new driver and guides. However, after updating my system yesterday I noticed that after a reboot the WiFi had gone again. I went through the guide again and have got it working but now the signal is sitting at 1 bar even though I'm right next to the router.

I've tried adding the file `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` with `options rtl8723be ant_sel=1` and with `ant_sel=2` or `ant_sel=0`. Still don't have a better signal. I know this works fine in Windows, but for university I'd much rather stick with a linux OS instead of going back to Windows.

I noticed that doing this worked till I restart then it wouldn't work on 2nd attempt.

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be 
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Any advice would be great. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wi-Fi doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (RTL8723BE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wi-fi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-rtl8723be). It seems kernel v4.15.0-33 (and probably -34 too) has a bug, see this too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be

Comment: Hi. I've tried the solution from that question. The driver from lwfinger didn't seem to fix this issue either.

Comment: Try switching to an older kernel if possible.