# Will updating kernel to 4.15.0.34 ruin rtl8723be functioning?

Tags: rtl8723be

I tried to install 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04 and I had a problem with RTL8723BE wireless adapter. I followed this:

[Wi-Fi doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (RTL8723BE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068826/wi-fi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-rtl8723be)

Unfortunately, that didn't work. I also tried installing 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04, and tried this solution:

[How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

It had worked for 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04, but for 64 bit it didn't work.

I read that there is a bug of kernel 4.15.0.34, which is the kernel that in both attempts the system was using.

Finally, I installed 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04, and followed the second link, and it worked (as it had worked in the past).

My question is the following: This installation uses kernel 4.4.0-31. If I update the packages with `sudo apt-get upgrade`, will that ruin the current functioning of the adapter?

Comment: To answer your question, someone needs to test it on your specific hardware. It is unlikely that someone would be a fellow Ubuntu user from another city or country, so the most practical scenario is for you to test, and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `sudo apt-get upgrade` nor `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` upgrade the system to a newer release or change it to the HWE version. They will just update the system to the latest packages that have been released for the specific release that's installed. The kernel version will remain in the range 4.4.0-x.

If you want to update the kernel to the next 4.4.0-x version though, you have to use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` otherwise `sudo apt-get upgrade` will not update it at all.

The is no chance any newer kernel, like 4.15 for example, will get installed by using either of these two commands if the existing version is 4.4.0-x because it's the GA kernel. Not the HWE kernel.