# HP Pavillion ay012nx Wi-Fi not working properly on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I purchased a HP laptop with model number **hp 15-ay012nx**. The Wi-Fi works perfectly in Windows but is really very weak in Ubuntu that I can use Wi-Fi in laptop only when I place laptop very near to my modem. I tried to solve the issue with some related  results but, I think its not specific to my model. The network details are as follows.

```
  03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with Linux kernel 4.15.0-36-generic.

Comment: 4.15.0-36-generic . And I am facing this issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak) is the general solution for the issue with RTL8723BE devices. But this might not be enough as recent kernels starting with version 4.15.0-33 [have a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997). These may come in handy: https://askubuntu.com/q/1084979/480481, https://askubuntu.com/q/1069153/480481, and https://askubuntu.com/q/1068826/480481

Comment: Actually see https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04780827 and at step 12 move the wire from one connector to the other and then put the laptop back together