# Wi-Fi connection working only in the same room (RTL8723BE)

Tags: networking, wireless, connection, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 partition on my HP laptop (originally Windows 10). I am only able to connect to Wi-Fi while I am in the same room of the modem. When I go to another room I get the message "no networks available", even if other devices can connect and the "Windows part" too. I searched for problems like this, but I couldn't get a solution. I hope you can help me, thank you.

I tried `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`
This was the output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried `uname -r`, I got `4.15.0-36-generic`.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak) is the general solution for the issue with RTL8723BE devices. But this might not be enough as recent kernel versions starting with 4.15.0-33 have a bug. These may come in handy: https://askubuntu.com/q/1084979, https://askubuntu.com/q/1069153, and https://askubuntu.com/q/1068826