# Ubuntu 18.10 weak wifi signal

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.10, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

This is the same problem I faced in ubuntu 16.04 lts but it got resolved on following the steps mentioned [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2356493). I upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 lts and then also above steps worked for me. But in recent upgrade the steps above doesn't worked. In [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084979/wifi-signal-strength-weak-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) answer I read that upgrading to 18.10 will work because of kernel update but all in vain. I know there are many answers but all are same as above two I quoted. I've set ant_sel = 2(ant_sel = 1, doesn't work) and on running `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'`
 I too get signal info but it is very weak, initially the same used to excellent. There is no signal issue, now also it is drivers issue. If there are answers other than the ones I've quoted please refer, as I couldn't find.
Output on running `sudo lspci -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [8086:1916] (rev 07)    
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)  
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)  
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)  
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)  
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14] (rev f1)   
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9d15] (rev f1)    
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)     
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)    
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)      
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)     
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)     
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
```

Comment: Remember to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723-ant-sel.conf`.

Comment: Perhaps the well-known bug has re-emerged in 4.18.0-15. Is there any improvement if you select -14 at the GRUB menu and boot into -14 instead? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, did you try `ant_sel=0` ?

Comment: @heynnema, are you saying to make new file, if yes, then please elaborate little.

Comment: @chili555, there is no entry in grub for boot through 4.18.0-14 kernel, also ant_sel = 0 doesn't work also I don't know why but the ant_sel = 2 and 1 setting, now not giving any results for command "iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'"

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal yes, modify the file such that `ant_sel=0`, or 1, or 2. (hello @chili555)

Comment: Sorry, but there is no file like this so I don't know what to exactly put in this file. Please help. Also the file is to be named exactly what you described?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal If you follow the link that you gave in your question, the very first answer describes this file, and its contents.

Comment: @heynnema , I've done the steps of setting ant_sel = 0,1,2 but none worked, now as you described to make changes permanent by making file, done that too but no improvement.

Comment: What was the result of booting into an earlier kernel version?

Comment: @chili555, as you've described in one of your answers that 4.17 kernel version works in this case, I installed that and done as you described but the system after getting to 4.17 was not performing properly and also the wifi problem persists but I've not tried booting 18.10 with kernel version 4.15-x, should I do this?

Comment: Please try 4.8.0-14  and report back. After you are booted into -14, be sure to try `anf_sel=0` also =1 and also =2.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but nothing worked out for me so moved back to ubuntu 16.04.