# Wi-Fi adapter not found Ubuntu 18.04 with HP laptop

Tags: 18.04, linux-headers

Please help.
Wi-Fi adapter not found Ubuntu 18.04 with HP laptop
Followed steps mentioned under 
1) https://ibcomputing.com/install-rtl8723de-realtek-d723-ubuntu-18-04/#comment-73
2)[No wifi option on Ubuntu (18.04 and 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04)

No Luck !!

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de, wl

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 : Thanks. Updated and posted the output.lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
 Kernel modules: rtl8723de, wl

Comment: spci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319] Kernel modules: rtl8723de, wl

Comment: Next, please show the result of: rfkill list all

Comment: rfkill list all
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Still the same issue persists ....can someone help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (It worked for me)

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

After running above commands `Reboot` your system. 
If you notice a weak signal try:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1
```

and see if it is better, if not do

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

And then run following command so that you won't have to run above command everytime you boot your system

```
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=X" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

Replace X with whatever setting worked best. For me, X was 2.

Note: My laptop model is **`HP 15-bs145tu`**

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this couple of times but still no luck !!

Comment: sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
Module rtlwifi-new/0.6 already installed on kernel 4.15.0-34-generic/x86_64
It seems its there and installed on my machine

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723de && dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: Response is too long. Its exceeding the limit :) I can send you the reponse on your email id so that you can guide me further

Comment: Paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Still same issue persists ..can someone please help ?