# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found Ubuntu 18.04 on Desktop

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, ralink

First of all it is not duplicated I tried other solutions but not working.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5372 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I was facing the issue not showing the 5G wifi so I follow [No wifi option on Ubuntu (18.04 and 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04/1038807?noredirect=1#comment1766461_1038807) but now it is not showing any wifi option and message is 'No Wi-Fi Adapter Found' is coming.

Output of commands:

```
$ dmesg | grep rt2
[    3.885159]  (null): rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5392, rev 0223 detected
[    3.894865]  (null): rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5372 detected
[    3.894991] Modules linked in: intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper snd_hda_codec_realtek cryptd snd_hda_codec_generic rt2800usb(+) rt2x00usb rt2800lib snd_hda_intel rt2x00lib snd_hda_codec intel_cstate snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mac80211(OE) snd_pcm cfg80211(OE) snd_seq_midi compat(OE) snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq joydev snd_seq_device intel_rapl_perf snd_timer snd input_leds serio_raw soundcore mei_me mei shpchp acpi_pad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau mxm_wmi wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt e1000e fb_sys_fops drm ptp ahci pps_core libahci
[    3.895057]  rt2x00lib_probe_hw+0x39c/0x420 [rt2x00lib]
[    3.895058]  rt2x00lib_probe_dev+0x2e3/0x370 [rt2x00lib]
[    3.895060]  rt2x00usb_probe+0x1c2/0xc70 [rt2x00usb]
[    3.895063]  rt2800usb_probe+0x15/0x20 [rt2800usb]
[    3.895078]  rt2800usb_driver_init+0x23/0x1000 [rt2800usb]
[    3.895118]  (null): rt2x00lib_probe_dev: Error - Failed to initialize hw
[    3.895132] rt2800usb: probe of 1-6:1.0 failed with error -22
[    3.895147] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
```

Comment: What about "Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter"?

Comment: Your device is covered by the driver *rt2800usb* that is already included in Ubuntu 18.04. Please show us: `sudo modprobe rt2800usb` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555 both commands output is nothing.

Comment: How about: `dmesg | grep rt2`

Comment: @chili555 I have added the output in the question

Comment: "(null): rt2x00lib_probe_dev: Error - *Failed to initialize hw*" Could this be a hardware issue? Is the message the same in a different USB port? It is late; I am off for the evening.

Comment: @chili555 Yes error is same. And thank you for your support.

Comment: @mikewhatever can you please tell me how can I install the adapter for 'Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless'? Actually I am not expert of ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? Does the device work in Windows? Can you try the device in some other computer; does it work there? If you boot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu, does it work there?

Comment: No it is not a dual-boo. Yes this device is working on other commuters. How to boot into an earlier kenel version?