# Wifi Options in Ubuntu 18.04.02 Desktop Settings not available

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless

I'm trying to figure out how to re-activate the Wi-Fi options in Ubuntu 18.04.02 Desktop Settings:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot I've taken, there is no on/off button for wifi.

I followed the indications found here: [No wifi option on Ubuntu (18.04 and 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04) 
but without success ...

```
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 
802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5362 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for riccardo: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet  
Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: c8:d9:d2:ee:2a:29
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list   
ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd  
autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 
duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.5  
latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4204000-
a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
        description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4100000-a410ffff
```

1° Update:

Following the indications here: [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

```
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for riccardo: 
install -p -m 644 8821ce.ko  /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel
/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 5.0.0-37-generic
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo modprobe 
8821ce
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse:
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with 
'“options'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse:   
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 9: ignoring bad line starting with 
'“options'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8821ce': Operation not permitted
```

2° Update:

Following the indications found here: [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ sudo apt-get install 
--reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not 
upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5.147 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 208318 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) over (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.7) over (2.3-3ubuntu9.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5) over (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.0.0-37-  
generic_5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic (5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1) over 
(5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic (5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-37-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=5.0.0-37-generic.......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce:
v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic 
(x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108/build/make.log
for more information.
   ...done.
Setting up build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.7) ...
Setting up git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...

riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ git clone https://github.com
/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
Cloning into 'rtl8821ce'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 22, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 1495 (delta 5), reused 12 (delta 2), pack-reused 1473
Receiving objects: 100% (1495/1495), 5.72 MiB | 5.30 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (812/812), done.

riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ cd rtl8821ce
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ chmod +x dkms-
install.sh
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ chmod +x dkms-
remove.sh

riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo ./dkms-
install.sh
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20190614
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20190614 already built for kernel
 5.0.0-37-generic/4
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20190614 already installed on kernel 
5.0.0-37-generic/x86_64
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

I then disabled SecureBoot:

riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo mokutil 
    0--disable-validation
    password length: 8~16
    input password: 
    input password again: 
o

and rebooted.
  But still not able to see the options on/off for WiFi Settings.

What am I missing?

3° Update :

I removed the previous rtl8821ce folder, git cloned again rtl8821ce repository, removed the previous rtl8821ce installation, and re-installed again:

```
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo make install 
install -p -m 644 8821ce.ko  /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/kernel
/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 5.0.0-37-generic
riccardo@riccardo-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo ./dkms-
install.sh
About to run dkms install steps...

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20190614/source 
->
                 /usr/src/rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20190614

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=5.0.0-37-generic...............
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20190614/5.0.0-37-generic
/x86_64/module/8821ce.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

8821ce:
Running module version sanity check.

Good news! Module version v5.5.2_34066.20190614_COEX20180712-3232 for 
8821ce.ko
 exactly matches what is already found in kernel 5.0.0-37-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

Then I rebooted but still no wifi options in settings ....

How to solve the problem?

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried the suggestions in that page but still the wifi options are not available

Comment: This means that you failed to install the driver. There is nothing else to add. "Without success" doesn't give any information.

Comment: Try to disable secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 I updated my question with the error I got

Comment: I see that you have some crap in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`. Remove this file. You don't need it anyway if you are not using an Intel adapter.

Comment: And a better solution is with dkms install.

Comment: @Pilot6 I updated my question with 2° Update with the steps followed and still missing something

Comment: There is no need to post screenshots of settings. The module doesn't build for some reason. There are errors. Maybe you broke something on previous attempts. It won't work unless it builds correctly.

Comment: @Pilot6 As you can see from the output of each single command line step, no error were produced

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102910/discussion-between-user2315094-and-pilot6).

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot?