# Wifi stopped working after Ubuntu update

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi

I have been running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS for quite a time on my HP pavilion au111tx. Recently some update came which looked like a regular update which I installed, and after restarting Iam facing wifi issues. It now complains

> No wifi adapter found

> Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on

I tried some solutions I found online but none worked for me. I have updated my kernel version to  5.3.0-43-generic.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

The Bluetooth is working fine

```
rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Some solutions involved installing Realtek drivers. My Ethernet is fine. Now I am posting this question from the same laptop which has wifi issues but no problem in connecting to mobile via USB tethering.

```
lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2110
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

When I turn off Bluetooth it is turning on aeroplane mode. I hope that is expected one.

I will be happy to post whatever logs you require to make my wifi work again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reboot. At the GRUB menu, select the older kernel.  File a bug report for the reversion, so developers will be informed.

Comment: I have selected a 4.15 version kernel from GRUB.still seeing the same message when trying to access the wifi from settings.

Comment: Are you saying that the wireless failure occurs in all kernel versions that you have installed? If so, then it seems more like a hardware failure than a software reversion.

Comment: Thing is i don't have that many kernel versions to switch.I only have the latest one i installed and one more 4.15 version.The wifi works fine in my windows.My machine is dual booted and problem started in this past week.

Comment: Did you need to install anything special or twiddle any settings to make your WiFi work originally?

Comment: When i installed ubuntu like a year back i think i came across similar problem but it was fine then. I was using ubuntu 16 back then and upgraded to 18.04 in a couple of months.The issue surfaced quite recently suddenly wifi stopped working.I don't know if i need to upgrade or degrade the version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106014/discussion-between-thakur-karthik-and-user535733).

Comment: I will post more information if you guys need. @user535733

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue after updating some drivers after following some other answers in this site