# "No WIFI adapter found" on dell precision 5510 with intel wireless 6280 card

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, wireless, dell, iwlwifi

so I want to start off saying I'm sorry for asking a question that has a lot of Help already, but I've tried most of what I can find.
I'm very new to Linux, currently in my first semester for CompSci so bare with me please.

I am running a dual boot on my on my Dell Precision 5510, i7,16gb RAM, NvidiaM1000m Quaddro, 1TB SSD and the intel wireless 6280. i recently downloaded the newest version of 20.04LTS Ubuntu, Used Rufus to create a bootable thumb drive. it all seems to have worked correctly EXCEPT it cant get it to communicate with the Wifi card in my PC.
I can tether my phone to my PC and it will have internet access then.
i used the "try ubuntu" option first, everything seemed fine besides wifi, i figured it would be a simple driver fix, and decided to install it. followed the steps, created partition, and done.

i thought it might just be a Ubuntu problem, so i tried Linux mint and Manjara running off a bootable thumb drive to see if wifi worked with them. to no avail.so i am thinking that for some reason Windows Or Dell have some kind of block not allowing the Wireless card to function with Linux on a dual boot option?

im willing to attempt any suggestions given.

```
william@william-Precision-5510:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)

william@william-Precision-5510:~$ rfkill list all
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

william@william-Precision-5510:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for william: 
[    2.047721] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.141827] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for the Assistance. i made the edit you requested

Comment: Is the hybrid shutdown of Windows disabled?  Have you tried resetting BIOS to defaults?

Comment: i attempted turning off the hybrid shutdown.(that is under the power settings for essentially a quick start on windows right?) when i did it it didnt fix anything so i turned it back on. leave off?   i have not reset the BIOS settings. i can attempt it thought.

Comment: `Hard blocked: yes` This suggests that the wireless switch or key combination (perhaps Fn+F7 or similar) is set to disable the wireless radio. Please find it and switch it.

Comment: https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/Notebooks/Dell/Precision_5510/DSC03353_Kopie.jpg PrtScr, it seems.

Comment: okay FN+prtscr turned off airplane mode, but now i cant even find a WIFI setting in my settings.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: im trying to figure out how to edit my question with the code posted the correct way so its not all stacked up. but your request has been added

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04

Comment: i followed this directions i just found and it fixed my problem.i didnt see it until 20 minutes ago, i think because i was looking for a thread with a newer version of Ubuntu. thank you for the assistance guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

[No wifi option on Ubuntu (18.04 and 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04)

i followed the steps on this thread and solved the No wifi Issue.