# Wifi Not working on First boot Ubuntu20.04

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, dell

I am running a dual boot on my on my Dell Precision 5510, Windows 10Pro, i7-6820HQ, 16gb RAM, Nvidia M1000 Quadro, 1TB SSD and the Intel wireless 6280.

so initially when i created the dual boot i was having a problem getting Ubuntu to recognize my Wifi card. ( ["No WIFI adapter found" on dell precision 5510 with intel wireless 6280 card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312510/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-dell-precision-5510-with-Intel-wireless-6280-card/1312559#1312559) ) this is the original question for reference.

my current issue is a little different and not as important, its merely a inconvenience. When i turn my laptop on the default OS is Ubuntu, so if i don't go to the Boot-loader menu it goes straight to Ubuntu. on the FIRST load of the OS my WiFi will not work, same issue as my previous post, WiFi is simply not even an option in the settings, it doesn't appear.

But, if i restart the PC it works like it is supposed to and i have WiFi. any ideas on what could possibly be wrong? or maybe a solution? thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a possible fix? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: You again! i remember you from your help the last time i was having issues, thank you again. this is actually a good idea. it was a suggested fix the last time, but it wasn't the solution for that issue. it might be for this one. ill give it a go now. and update you in a few.

Comment: that seems to have done the trick. WiFi was working on initial start up. thanks for the help!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks!