# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS no WiFi

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 20.04

I am a new Ubuntu user so I have a lot of kinks to work through. I have seen a lot of amazing support on this thread, so I thought I give it a shot.

I am on a **Lenovo IdeaPad S145**, with **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** installed on a **clean partition** of my SATA HDD. I did not install alongside Windows, which is on my M.2 SSD.

I am currently experiencing a weird issue where there is no option available for connecting to wifi networks. When I select the drop down menu on the top right of the screen, I see options for wired connections, but nothing for wifi.

rfkill shows my wifi device. However, when I go to Wi-Fi in the settings menu, there are no wifi adapters found and running ifconfig returns an error.

```
(base) waleed@waleed-Laptop:~/backport-iwlwifi$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth   blocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0                blocked unblocked
(base) waleed@waleed-Laptop:~/backport-iwlwifi$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

[Screenshot of settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBXbA.png)

I have tried the following to resolve the issue with no success:

- Updating with `sudo apt upgrade`
- Ensuring the BiOS 'Secure Boot' setting is disabled (it was).
- Disabling Fast-Boot in the BiOS.
- Following the instructions suggested by chili555 in this post
  ([No wifi option on Ubuntu (18.04 and 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04)).

When I ran the `sudo make` in the above article, it would run normally, but then hang at a certain point for over 5 minutes. I interrupted the task after 6 or so minutes of waiting, restarted the computer fully and then ran `make clean` followed by `make` and now the terminal hangs after the first line. I have currently been waiting for 20 minutes and my output is as seen below.

```
(base) waleed@waleed-Laptop:~/backport-iwlwifi$ sudo make
  GEN     /home/waleed/backport-iwlwifi/net/wireless/shipped-certs.c
```

My best guess is this is not working as it was written for Ubuntu 18.04, but I'm not sure if that's a valid assumption.

Not sure what my next step should be or if Windows might be locking the WiFi card somehow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: If I left any important information out, please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: The steps you linked to by chili555 are specific to a single chipset among the myriads on the market. Each chipset has its own problems and solutions. Find your chipset (`lspci -knn | grep Network`) and then look it up in the Search box at the top of this page.

Comment: @user535733 You are blessing my friend. I didn't have the package installed for my chipset. Got it installed and everything is working fine now. Thank You!!!!