# WiFi suddenly disappeared Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, network-manager, lenovo

I am using dual boot with Windows 10. Wifi on Windows works without issues.

**Notebook model:** Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH

There was no problem with wifi on Ubuntu for about 2 months. Yesterday I tried to connect to a new wifi and I didn't spell the password correctly on the first try. After a few moments wifi menu disappeared from settings.

Here are the results of some commands I've tried:

**ifconfig:**

```
michal@Legion:~$ ifconfig
br-d478e4b92f5a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:77ff:fe5a:9982  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:77:5a:99:82  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27  bytes 756 (756.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 431  bytes 57770 (57.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:7d:fd:05:05  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp8s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.166  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::e23d:98d6:1413:df9b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e8:6a:64:72:fb:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20050  bytes 8166760 (8.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13548  bytes 2488670 (2.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5729  bytes 491310 (491.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5729  bytes 491310 (491.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth0c7b145: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::54a4:d7ff:fed0:39c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 56:a4:d7:d0:39:c4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 345  bytes 22320 (22.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 765  bytes 83702 (83.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth5369aec: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7897:54ff:fe99:37f5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7a:97:54:99:37:f5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11  bytes 772 (772.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 589  bytes 67742 (67.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth889aba9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5031:2aff:fe9f:61d9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:31:2a:9f:61:d9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 579  bytes 67032 (67.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:be:4e:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**iwconfig:**

```
michal@Legion:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-d478e4b92f5a  no wireless extensions.

veth5369aec  no wireless extensions.

veth0c7b145  no wireless extensions.

veth889aba9  no wireless extensions.
```

**lspci:**

```
michal@Legion:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake H] (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

**rfkill list all:**

```
michal@Legion:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**What I've tried:**

- Checking if wifi is allowed in BIOS
- Reinstalling drivers: [Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS no WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318556/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-no-wifi)
- [Wifi doesnt work on fresh ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893384/wifi-doesnt-work-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-04/893442#893442) - This didn't work however it might be related because the problem was with a similar notebook model.

Comment: Please try `nmcli network off && nmcli network on`

Comment: My wired connection got disabled too and enp8s0 disappeared from ifconfig output. Back to normal after reboot, still no wifi, outputs of commands are the same.

Comment: Ensure that Windows fast start is also off (you have to start Windows and go into the settings menu for this) then goto your BIOS/UEFI and make sure you are in UEFI mode,  and that secure boot is off.