# Wifi option not showing on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I'm using pavilion with ryzen5 5625u. I already tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04) and disabled secure boot according another answer. I also ran `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` but it says it failed to restart . I also went to software and update for additional drivers, but it has no additional drivers to install.
[it says no wifi adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD4xE.png)
output of  `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
[output of cat command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW3QQ.png)

this is the output of **`ip a # check if you can see wireless card`**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:be:a8:da:f2:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.182/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 3593sec preferred_lft 3593sec
    inet6 fe80::2ace:eaf0:c3ba:8cf9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and output of **`lspci -knn | grep Network -A3 # This shows card name and driver, if in use.`**

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:712 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980 [144d:a809]
```

**Edit 1**
output of my ifconfig is

```
$ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 488  bytes 60829 (60.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 488  bytes 60829 (60.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx200db01052d8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::45dc:7ce4:395e:7bf1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 20:0d:b0:10:52:d8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12242  bytes 14993668 (14.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9344  bytes 1371773 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and output of ifup and ifdown is

```
ifup: no interface(s) specified
ifup: Use --help for help
```

Comment: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf ` please add this to your question through [edit] there is a parse error ; kmod gives a warning.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2WDYMlX  this is the output of the command

Comment: it says no wifi adapter when i went to settings

Comment: remove the line beginning with `"options iwlwifi and so on"`  in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`and make a reboot. And please no images cp & paste the next time output from commands and [edit] your question for showing. this only remove the error from kmod.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is any help, however I am using 22.04.1 Server. I am using a built in wi-fi card and I am connected. However in the GUI it does not show me using wi-fi according to the icon and the drop down. This is what my interfaces look like:

```
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:b1:0a:f1:5e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 38:60:77:83:9c:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 199  bytes 18849 (18.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 199  bytes 18849 (18.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.27  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::76de:2bff:fe3c:bab3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:de:2b:3c:ba:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1532  bytes 814657 (814.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 957  bytes 167662 (167.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

interface wlp2s0 is my wifi card. Maybe use $ ifdown and $ ifup to see if that works for your situation. (sudo apt install net-tools if you don't have them already)

Hope this helps.

Comment: output of my ifconfig is posted on question, pls check it out