# No option to connect Wifi in 22.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 22.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 recently. My system is also a dual-boot with Windows. Everything had been going well until recently the computer crashed due to running out of batteries. Now, there is no longer a networking option. I attempted the fixes from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038242/no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04), but to no effect. I also confirmed fast-boot is turned off in Windows. The wifi works fine in Windows.

Here is information I gleaned from the standard commands:

```
    sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:80500000-8050ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: b
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: enx00e04c6809e9
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:09:e9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.12 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=10.0.0.66 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2753 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34bf (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5410 (rev 01)
```

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The script from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) gives the output [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Rg48qgZMzd/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please open Software & Updates and click the Additional Drivers tab. Is there an option to insyall rtl8821ce-dkms? If so, please do so and reboot.

Comment: @chili555 it notes ""this device is using an alternative driver" says "Using DKMS source for the Realtek 8821C PCle wifi driver from rtl8821ce-dkms (open source)".

Comment: @waltinator I have uploaded the output from the script from that page. Please let me know what to do next.

Comment: @chili555 So anyway, rtl8821ce-dkms IS installed, but nonetheless, the problem persists.

Comment: Does the command: `sudo modprobe rtl8821ce && sudo dmesg | grep 8821` give us any clues?

Comment: That command yields: ```modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8821ce': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)```

Comment: @chili555 That command yields: ```modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8821ce': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)```

Comment: Do `cd backport-iwlwifi && sudo make uninstall` then reboot

Comment: That sounds like an answer that I'd upvote @Jeremy31 !

Comment: @Jeremy31 That worked, thanks so much! So can you explain what exactly was going on here?

Comment: The backports use special kernel modules to make them work with older kernels and since your driver was built on the older kernel it wasn't compatible resulting with the unknown symbol in module error as it was likely trying to communicate with the newer cfg80211 module

Answer (score 1):

```
cd backport-iwlwifi && sudo make uninstall
```

Command from @Jeremy31 solved the problem. Thanks!